Binance - Spot Market Profit Calculator
I have a Python method that calculates the profit after taking into account the commission structure. However, it fails to replicate the exact values from Binance trade history. For example I bought ETH/USDT using LIMIT order at a price of 2595 with a buy amount of 57.609 USDT. Then I sold using LIMIT order at a price of 2700. As per my understanding the precision value for this pair is 8 but still the calculator fails to give correct results. Below is the code I am using.
def calculate_profit_after_commission_binance(buy_price: float, buy_amount_usdt: float, sell_price: float, 
                                       order_type_buy: str = 'MARKET', order_type_sell: str = 'MARKET',
                                       fee_rate_maker: float = 0.001, fee_rate_taker: float = 0.001) -> float:
    if order_type_buy == 'MARKET':
        buy_fee_rate = fee_rate_taker
    else:
        buy_fee_rate = fee_rate_maker

    if order_type_sell == 'MARKET':
        sell_fee_rate = fee_rate_taker
    else:
        sell_fee_rate = fee_rate_maker

    # Calculate the amount of asset bought
    asset_quantity = buy_amount_usdt / buy_price
    
    # Deduct commission on the asset bought
    asset_quantity_available = asset_quantity * (1 - buy_fee_rate)
    
    # Selling commission in USDT
    sell_commission = asset_quantity_available * sell_price * sell_fee_rate

    # Profit after sell commission
    profit = asset_quantity_available * sell_price - sell_commission - buy_amount_usdt
    
    return profit



Have you tried using the decimal Module? It's more precise than `float'. See python library decimal vs. float.

Since you can only sell up to 4 decimal place of the available asset. Below is the correct implementation. Remaining asset after 4 decimal places stays in account and can be converted to BNB.
from decimal import Decimal, ROUND_DOWN

def truncate_to_precision(value, precision=4):
    # Convert the float to Decimal
    decimal_value = Decimal(value)
    # Quantize the Decimal to the specified precision
    truncated_value = decimal_value.quantize(Decimal(f'1.{"0" * precision}'), rounding=ROUND_DOWN)
    return float(truncated_value)


def calculate_profit_after_commission_binance(buy_price: float, buy_amount_usdt: float, sell_price: float, precision: int,
                                       order_type_buy: str = 'MARKET', order_type_sell: str = 'MARKET',
                                       fee_rate_maker: float = 0.001, fee_rate_taker: float = 0.001) -> float:
    if order_type_buy == 'MARKET':
        buy_fee_rate = fee_rate_taker
    else:
        buy_fee_rate = fee_rate_maker

    if order_type_sell == 'MARKET':
        sell_fee_rate = fee_rate_taker
    else:
        sell_fee_rate = fee_rate_maker

    # Calculate the amount of asset bought
    asset_quantity = buy_amount_usdt / buy_price
    
    # Deduct commission on the asset bought
    asset_quantity_available = asset_quantity * (1 - buy_fee_rate)

    asset_quantity_available_sell = truncate_to_precision(asset_quantity_available, 4)
    
    # Selling commission in USDT
    sell_commission = asset_quantity_available_sell * sell_price * sell_fee_rate

    # Profit after sell commission
    profit = asset_quantity_available_sell * sell_price - sell_commission - buy_amount_usdt
    
    return profit


The reason for the mismatch in profit calculation and Binance trade is due to the difference in the asset quantity available and the sell order quantity. From your method calculation and provided in put, asset_quantity_available should be 0.0221778. However, on the sell order, the quantity of asset sold was 0.0221. My guess is that Binance can only allow 4 digits of floating point accuracy in their sell order and round down the remainder to avoid overselling. I think you can perform this round down operation using math.floor function in python
asset_quantity_available_rounded = math.floor(asset_quantity_available * 10000) / 10000.0

When you use the rounded asset quantity available to calculate the selling fee, you would see that fee is 0.05967 which matches with the sell order fee of 0.05967 USDT. When you multiply asset_quantity_available_rounded and sell_price, you would see that the total sell price for the is 59.67 USDT not excluding the selling fee, which matches with the number on the sell order above
I think your calculation is correct but the mismatch is due to having the sell amount different from the amount actually available. You can add the flooring calculation in your function like the code below
import math

def calculate_profit_after_commission_binance(buy_price: float, buy_amount_usdt: float, sell_price: float, 
                                       order_type_buy: str = 'MARKET', order_type_sell: str = 'MARKET',
                                       fee_rate_maker: float = 0.001, fee_rate_taker: float = 0.001) -> float:
    if order_type_buy == 'MARKET':
        buy_fee_rate = fee_rate_taker
    else:
        buy_fee_rate = fee_rate_maker

    if order_type_sell == 'MARKET':
        sell_fee_rate = fee_rate_taker
    else:
        sell_fee_rate = fee_rate_maker

    # Calculate the amount of asset bought
    asset_quantity = buy_amount_usdt / buy_price
    
    # Deduct commission on the asset bought
    asset_quantity_available = asset_quantity * (1 - buy_fee_rate)

    # Round down the asset quantity tradable on binance
    asset_quantity_available_floor = math.floor(asset_quantity_available * 10000) / 10000.0
    
    # Selling commission in USDT
    sell_commission = asset_quantity_available_floor * sell_price * sell_fee_rate

    # Profit after sell commission
    profit = asset_quantity_available_floor * sell_price - sell_commission - buy_amount_usdt
    
    return profit


this would fail in other cases, precision should be used over floor and a precision value should be passed explicitly. This should fix the issue. Can you use precision over floor in your answer?
